# Bones Not Showing In Pose Mode

Tags: armature

Heyo,

Bones are not showing up in pose mode/object for me. They only appear in edit mode.
There is no visibility to toggle (I've still tried right clicking and using the 'unhide option' but nothing.) I also have 'In Front' active.[image]

[image]

Comment: You are in Blender sculpt mode. Try saving the object as an STL, and rigging it in default Blender.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my issue.